# get number of rows in a table in selenium webdriver in "javascript"

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

M aware of a "bunch" of similar questions. But none helped me since most were java oriented; i tried many possible combinations of size() and length. But no success so far.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@name='leavesHistoryGrid']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")).then(function(tableRows){
    console.log("no of tableRows :",tableRows.size())
})
```

Comment: Did you try `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@name='leavesHistoryGrid']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")).length`?

Comment: In the 'then' function use length instead, as a promise is returned which will resolve to an array of webelements.

Comment: Thank u @Grasshopper. It works.. Dont know how I missed it.